# bash: grep wildcard start and end with

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

i have a bash script like this:

```
TABLE_TO_IGNORE=$(mysql -u $DBUSER -p$DBPASS -h $DBHOST  -N <<< "show tables from $DBNAME" | grep "^$i" | xargs);
```

currently i only able to grep the text starting with. How to write the code that to determine the text ending with?

**let say 1:**

my $i is: 
test1_*
tb2_*
tb3_*

with the * at the back part, it will grep as text starting with those value

**let say 2:**

my $i is:
*_sometext1
*sometext2

with the * at the front, it will grep as text ending with those value.

i know this:
grep '^sometext1' files = 'sometext1' at the start of a line
grep 'sometext2$' files = 'sometext2' at the end of a line

**question is:** how do i write the if else to my bash code identify the * is in front or back?

**Note:** You can ignore my bash code, i just need the if else condition to determine the "*" is in front or at the back of the string.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
#!/bin/bash

stringToTest="Hello World!*" 

echo $stringToTest | grep "^\*.*" > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "Asterisk is at the front" 
fi

echo $stringToTest | grep "^.*\*$" > /dev/null 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "Asterisk is at the back" 
fi
```

As shown in this code, I made use of exit code (`$?`) to determine whether the regular expression matches the string. As shown in [man grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

> Normally, **exit status is 0 if selected lines are found** and 1
>   otherwise.

Hope this helps.